# Print over Previous Lines

Tags: python

Is it possible to overwrite *any* past print statement in Python 3? For example, let's say our current output is:

```
Hello!
Planet!
Earth!
```

And now I want to overwrite the first line ("Hello!"), but not output a new line to do so. Is this possible? i.e.

```
Awesome!
Planet!
Earth!
```

Side note: My application is working in a Jupyter notebook, where this would be aesthetically pleasing.

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't skip a line, you can always use carriage return, but not like this I guess.

Comment: So do you think this is impossible?